# How to read a text file containing strings into an array in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm trying to read a text file into an associative array. For example, 'text.txt' contains

```
1. ABC
2. XYZ
```

I'd like to read this text file and print them out such such `Array[0]` is `1. ABC` and `Array[1]` is `2. XYZ`

I have 6 lines of input in total!

Here is what I have right now

```
program readText
OPEN(1,FILE='text.txt')
    READ(1, *) A ,B, C, D, E, F
    WRITE (*, *) A,B,C,D, E ,F
CLOSE(1)
end program readText
```

After this i get

```
Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x10bde99ac
#1  0x10bdea645
#2  0x10bdeadd9
#3  0x10bfb3ecb
#4  0x10bfacab6
#5  0x10bfae509
#6  0x10bdddc82
#7  0x10bddde78
```

Hence, i am not even printing the text file to the screen. After this, I'd like to assign them into an array and print the array. Please let me know what I could do to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try good ol google ? And BTW which kind of fortran...https://www.math.fsu.edu/~dmandel/Fortran/ReadingArrayData.pdf or https://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_77/15_files.html

Comment: @ThomasLudewig Thanks for your reply! I will look at them. and Fortran90!

Comment: That was the first hit in "fortran read file in array" :D

Comment: BTW: https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/f_src.html Secret tip ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide you an example where the content of the text file is written into a dynamic character array. If you are using FORTRAN then I highly recommend you to use explicit variable declaration. This can be forced by the command

```
implicit none
```

Otherwise you have to care about the implicit variable definition of FORTRAN, which can be found [here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jhm/f90/lectures/deftype.html):

> Variables beginning with I .. N are `INTEGER`
>   Variables beginning with other letters are `REAL`

Extending your input file `text.txt` to 6 lines:

```
1. ABC
2. XYZ
3. FOO
4. BAR
5. BYE
6. CKE
```

Please use this program to create and fill the character array as well as to print it to standard output:

```
program readText
implicit none

integer :: FID = 1
character*256 :: CTMP

! 1. Assuming that no line of text.txt contains more than 256 characters
character*256, allocatable :: MY_ARRAY(:)
integer :: I = 0, IERR = 0, NUM_LINES = 0

open(unit=FID,file='text.txt')

! 2. Get number of lines
do while (IERR == 0)
  NUM_LINES = NUM_LINES + 1
  read(FID,*,iostat=IERR) CTMP
end do
NUM_LINES = NUM_LINES - 1
write(*,'(A,I0)') "Number of lines = ", NUM_LINES

! 3. Allocate array of strings
allocate(MY_ARRAY(NUM_LINES))

! 4. Read the file content
rewind(FID)
do I = 1, NUM_LINES
  read(FID,'(A)') MY_ARRAY(I)
end do

! 5. Print array to standard output
do I = 1,size(MY_ARRAY,1)
  write(*,*) trim(MY_ARRAY(I))
end do

deallocate(MY_ARRAY)
close(FID)

end program readText
```

The output looks like this:

```
Number of lines = 6
 1. ABC
 2. XYZ
 3. FOO
 4. BAR
 5. BYE
 6. CKE
```

Hope it helps.